# check if route is valid react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react router v5 and would like to check my routes to make sure they are valid as my 404 page is not triggering when an invalid link is shown presumably because the route still matches even though there is no item to display on the route as it's invalid. e.g `example.com/cat1/product1` being valid and `example.com/cat1/produc1` being invalid.

The same for the categories `example.com/cat1` being valid and `example.com/ca1` being invalid.

Currently it just shows no content for the invalid link instead of my `NotFound` component.

How can I check each link to see if it is valid and if not display my `NotFound` component?

```
  <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home categories={categories} products={products} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/product-categories">
              <Products categories={categories} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/delivery">
              <Delivery categories={categories} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/terms">
              <Terms categories={categories} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/privacy">
              <Privacy categories={categories} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/returns">
              <Returns categories={categories} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/about">
              <About categories={categories} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/sitemap.xml" onEnter={reload}/>
            <Route path="/robots.txt" onEnter={reload}/>
            <Route exact path="/:catSlug">
              <ProductsList categories={categories} products={products} userCountry={userCountry}/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/:catSlug/:productSlug">
              <Product alertIsVisble={() => dispatch(allActions.showAlert())} categories={categories} products={products} userCountry={userCountry} />
            </Route>
            <Route>
              <NotFound categories={categories} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
```

Comment: That is something you have to handle in your component. when for given Id, data not found. redirect to 404.

Comment: @VaritJPatel is right, reactRouter won't know what is valid in case of `/:catSlug/:productSlug`  path. you replace anything with its placeholder it will be directed to your component. Now at component/container side you can make a decision whether it is valid or not

Comment: Adding to it.. reactRouter provide a hook, it can help too https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Hooks/useroutematch